# Usage bars from google charts as buttons

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

I have found nice way to generate charts using `Google charts API`.

Here is what I created http://jsfiddle.net/Mithrand1r/CnRtD/1/

Its just repeated one chart six times. First one one can be expanded ( by clicking on it).

And now is the question I have got. Can I use columns on this chart as a buttons? What I mean is that I want to generate another chart after user click on specific column on the chart he is looking at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "select" event:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        // then we selected something
        // most charts only support one selected element, so it is typically safe to do this:
        var row = selection[0].row;
        var column = selection[0].column;
        if (row == null) {
            // then someone clicked on the legend
        }
        else {
            // then someone clicked a chart element (bar, column, point, etc)
            // get any relevant data from the DataTable using the #getValue and/or #getFormattedValue methods
            // eg:
            var val = data.getValue(row, column);
            // do something with val
        }
    }
    else {
        // then we deselected all previously selected elements
    }
});
```

Comment: It works when I have only one chart. While my page contains few, `getSelecton()` method is breaking whole script..

Comment: the `getSelection` method is independent of the number of charts on your page, so it is likely that you have a different problem.  Post the updated code that you are using or an updated jsfiddle and I'll take a look.